# SQL Server - SSRS - Display the content of a Table/View directly in the report (and not using table/matrix)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

We have a View in SQL Server that constantly evolving.

We want to show it in a report as it is (If we add/remove a field in the View, we don't have to modify the report and add/remove manuelly the field).

A sort of a table/matrix that is refreshing by itself.

Thank you by advance for your help.

Comment: As Alan mentioned, it may be technically possible, but it's really not maintainable. You should use a `Table` and update the report when changes are made. Otherwise, SSRS isn't the right tool for this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using a table or matrix? Why not? You can't really do this without using one of these controls...

Ignoring that for a moment though, the problem you will face is that the dataset query has to always return the same structure every time it is run so you can't point it directly at a query that is constantly changing.

The only way you might be able to do this is to write a query that unpivots your table/view into another structure and then report on that. By using a matrix, you could reconstruct the table in the report.

There are drawbacks to this approach. All value data needs to be cast to a constant datatype so if each row has a mix of text and numeric values, they would all have to be converted to text.

This approach also assumes there is a key column on the table/view.

Below is a simple example of the kind of thing I mean. This is based on the sample 'AdventureWorksDW2016' database in case you want to test it.

```
DECLARE @Schema sysname = 'dbo' -- Schema where table/view resides
DECLARE @Table sysname = 'DimGeography' -- name of table or view to read from
DECLARE @KeyColumn sysname = 'GeographyKey' -- name of keycolumn, assumed to be INT in this exmaple

    SELECT 
        COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION, DATA_TYPE
    into #t
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS t 
      WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @Schema AND TABLE_NAME = @Table
      AND COLUMN_NAME != @KeyColumn
      
    DECLARE @OrdPos int 
    DECLARE @ColName sysname 
    DECLARE @sql varchar(max) = ''
    
    CREATE TABLE #result (KeyID int, ColumnName sysname, ColumnPosition int, ColumnValue varchar(75)) -- <= Update 75 to suit maximum column length
    
    WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #t)
        BEGIN
            SELECT TOP 1 @OrdPos = ORDINAL_POSITION, @ColName = COLUMN_NAME FROM #t
    
            SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO #result SELECT ' + @KeyColumn + ', ''' + @ColName + ''', ' + CAST(@OrdPos as varchar(10)) + ', CAST(' + @ColName + ' as varchar(200)) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@Schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@Table) 
            EXEC (@sql)
    
            DELETE FROM #t WHERE ORDINAL_POSITION = @OrdPos
        END
    
    SELECT * FROM #result
```

If we take a look at the results (just for 2 keyid vales for simplicity) we can see we have a consistent structure.

```
SELECT * FROM #result where keyid in (207,208) order by KeyID, ColumnPosition
```

[image]

Now, you can build a simple report using a Matrix, have a row group that groups by `KeyID` and have a column group that groups by `ColumnName`. The column group sorting can be set to `ColumnPosition` and the matrix 'data' cell set to `ColumnValue`.

This whole process will effectively recreate the table/view and be dynamic.