# Need to add dynamic columns in headers in SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I need to add column headers in `SSRS` report but that are dynamic in nature. 
For example, sometimes `Query` will return 5 different named columns with it's data and sometime will return 9 different named columns with it's data and so on.

So how to drag or refresh columns in `Dataset` and how to show in `SSRS` report dynamically.
I am totally confused seen many articles but not able to get solution.

How to implement this in `SSRS` report. I have the query, depending on parameters columns gets generated. Check below sample report preview
[image: Sample Report Preview]

its showing date in different columns

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In SSRS , the dataset must always return the same number of columns with the same names and datatypes, so you cannot of what you want directly.

You have two options.

---

Option 1

---

**Normalise the data.**

So instead of returning something like

```
SomeID    ColumnA  ColumnB ColumnC
1         10       20      30
2         15       25      35
3         100      200     300
```

You need to return

```
SomeID    ColName    Amount
1         'ColumnA'  10
1         'ColumnB'  20
1         'ColumnC'  30
2         'ColumnA'  15
2         'ColumnB'  25
2         'ColumnC'  35
3         'ColumnA'  10
3         'ColumnB'  200
3         'ColumnC'  300
```

Once you have your data in this format, you can simply use a matrix in your report. Set the rowgroup to `SomeID`, set the Column Group to `ColName` and the data value to `Amount`

This is by far the simplest solution.

---

Option 2

---

**Deconstruct and rebuild the table in code**

There are several drawbaks to this method but if you are interested, read my answer to this question asked a few days ago

[SQL Server - SSRS - Display the content of a Table/View directly in the report (and not using table/matrix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63260687/sql-server-ssrs-display-the-content-of-a-table-view-directly-in-the-report/63262514#63262514)

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5757/create-dynamic-ssrs-reports-using-a-query-as-an-input-parameter/#comments i used this but my sqltext is coming empty :(

Comment: hi i tried first option with matrix but iam getting data like this , please see snapshot

Comment: Edit you r question show your report design and the results. Also a sample of data as it comes out of your dataset would be useful.

Comment: i need to make report with dynamic columns headers at one time it could be 3 and other it could be 9. how to do it

Comment: My answer and linked answer in option 2 both show you how to do this.